# Manually scale features after fitting StandardScaler to data

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have scaled some training_data using Scikit Learns StandardScaler. Let's say I have stored this scaler in a variable called my_scaler.

Now I wanna use this my_scaler to scale some data I'll be getting from a form. However, I don't have access to my_scaler on the server that receives the form input.

So I'll need to somehow be able to export the parameters from my_scaler and then perform a manual scaling of the form data.

How can I do this?

I'm wondering both how I'd be able to export the parameters from my_scaler and how I'd use these parameters to perform a manual scaling on the data I'm getting from the form.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Look into pickle. https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingPickle